# Infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to understand how `vue` components work. The final goal is to add a line to the readonly `textarea` when I click my Go! button. At present I'm stuck with the following code:

```
// Register components
Vue.component('chatarea', {
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  props: ['msg'],
  template: '<textarea readonly="" rows="20">${msg}</textarea>',
})


// Create a root instance
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  data: {
      messages: [
        'Hello from Vue!',
        'Other line...'
      ],
  },
  methods: {
    get_msg: function () {
      return this.messages.reverse().join('\n');
    }
  }
})
```

The following `html` is rendered in the way I want it - messages are displayed in reverse order:

```
  <div class="container" id="app">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <form action="/question" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Say Something...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <chatarea :msg="get_msg()"></chatarea>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

However I'm getting the following warning:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

I understand I'm doing something wrong... Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxgdoakm/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template calls `get_msg` which recalculates the reversed message array which causes the template to re-render and call `get_msg`, etc.

Instead, use a computed.

```
computed:{
  reversedMessages(){
      return this.messages.slice().reverse().join('\n');
  }
},
```

And change your template to

```
<chatarea :msg="reversedMessages"></chatarea>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rxgdoakm/1/).

Comment: This is incorrect because [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) reverses the array *in place*, thus modifying the component state, which computed properties should not do. You should clone the array first before reversing it: `return this.messages.slice().reverse().join('\n')`.