# Vue.js infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, lodash

In composition to this issue which has been solved.
If I open multiple browser sessions with different users, it gets too buggy.
[composition post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075085/infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function)

`startedTyping` will call back-end service and Vuex store it.
In the view I get a list of who-is-typing, loop through it and display it on a condition.
`stoppedTyping` will remove the previous value from the store.

*EDIT*

In the view:

```xml
<template v-for="(typer,key) in typings">
    <p v-if="condition(typer)" v-bind:key="key">
        {{typer.name}}
    </p>
</template>
```

Comment: If you are using a function for checking the condition, have you checked that you are not changing any state inside that function?

Comment: Yes not changing state, the state changes only on stopped Typing, but the view hangs.

Comment: Check my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960887/infinite-loop-when-checking-roles-vuejs/62963352#62963352) to similar question and make sure that it is not your case.

Comment: Can you provide some more information? When you say it gets "too buggy" – what exactly is happening? How is `typings` calculated? What is `condition(typer)` (is it relevant)? Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @bigless, not related.

Comment: @Decade, Typings is a vuex list that gets added to once started typing, on stopped i clear the item added, but using vuex action inside debounce does clear the item but the view does not update. That is why i mean by buggy. otherwise i can have start Typing vuex action call the clear mutation after 5s the view updates.